# CSS label text right below input element

Tags: css

I have `input` text's and `label` tags. I can't figure out the CSS to get the label text to align right below the input text. Here's a snippet of the HTML:

```
<form id="sg1">
    <label for="member1">member 1</label>
    <input name="member1" id="member1" value="jack" />
    <label for="member2">member 2</label>
    <input name="member2" id="member2" value="carter" />
    <label for="member3">member 3</label>
    <input name="member3" id="member3" value="jackson" />
    <label for="member4">member 4</label>
    <input name="member4" id="member4" value="tielk" />    
</form>​
```

Trying to get:

```
[input box 1]    [input box 2]
      label 1          label 2
```

etc, with all elements.

Comment: I might be understanding something wrong, but have you tried putting the <label> _after_ the <input>?

Comment: Why don't you just put the label underneath it? And while you're at it, please accept some answers to your old questions.

Comment: For the record, they're *elements*, not tags.

Comment: is there a way to do without the <br /> basically to keep every input element on the same line, but the labels are right below each one. updated question with an ascii version of end result i am hoping to style

Comment: @You what's wrong with using "tag" loosely?!?! Do you use document.getElementsByTagName('...')

Comment: @ina You can use a table. Put each one in a cell.

Comment: @xander There's a distinct difference between *tags* and *elements*. Unfortunately, people tend to refer to everything as tags, which is just wrong and leads to confusion. In the case of `getElementsByTagName()`, you're getting all elements with a specific tag name (or type, if you will).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A quickly whipped up example that works:

```css
input {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 6em;
  position: relative;
  top: -3em;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 6em;
  margin-right: .5em;
  padding-top: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<form id="sg1">
  <label>member 1 <input name="member1" id="member1" value="jack" /></label>
  <label>member 2 <input name="member2" id="member2" value="carter" /></label>
  <label>member 3 <input name="member3" id="member3" value="jackson" /></label>
  <label>member 4 <input name="member4" id="member4" value="tielk" /></label>
</form>​
```

Could be improved, but I find it cleaner than extraneous `div`s, and it degrades much nicer than the `label`-after-`input`-approach when CSS support is absent. Personally, I prefer to nest the `input`s in the `label`s anyway.

Comment: @You Why did you add `relative` to `input`?

Comment: To position the input elements above their labels without chaning the HTML structure.

Comment: this is really cool. I had to use absolute positioning, due to having larger than normal inputs, however it works flawlessly. Quite impressive and very stange  - There's "ghost" height regions around the label.
I ended up making a visibility:hidden div containing a single input and single label with a <br> between. And when positioned absolutely, it flows just like a normal block element. Kudos.

Answer (score 5):

Use a table (one input/label pair per cell) or left-floating divs (one input/label pair per div). Example:

```
<div class="pair">
    <input type="text" name="foo" value="bar" /><br />
    <label for="foo">shabba</label>
</div>
<div class="pair">
    …
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.pair {
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: trying to avoid using the crutch of tables... tableless css and all, b ut not groking it. snippet for the float, please?

Answer (score 2):

You'd make the job a lot easier by wrapping each field (in this case, each input/label pair) in a div.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* use pure css to get this to achieve what you want, but it requires a lot of adhoc positioning stuff that you're better off not doing.

The simplest way is to put the label beneath the input on the html:

```
<form id="sg1">
    <input name="member1" id="member1" value="jack" />
    <label for="member1">member 1</label>
    <input name="member2" id="member2" value="carter" />
    <label for="member2">member 2</label>
    <input name="member3" id="member3" value="jackson" />
    <label for="member3">member 3</label>
    <input name="member4" id="member4" value="tielk" />    
    <label for="member4">member 4</label>
</form>
```

Then you can wrap each input/label pair with a div, and set the div like so:

```
<form id="sg1">
    <div class="wrap">
        <input name="member1" id="member1" value="jack" />
        <label for="member1">member 1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap">
        <input name="member2" id="member2" value="carter" />
        <label for="member2">member 2</label>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap">
        <input name="member3" id="member3" value="jackson" />
        <label for="member3">member 3</label>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap">
        <input name="member4" id="member4" value="tielk" />    
        <label for="member4">member 4</label>
    </div>
</form>

#sg1 div
{
    clear: both;
    float: left;
}
```

Next you can put

```
#sg1 label
{
    float: right;
}

input
{
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mT9SP/1/   

Look at it now: I added a display: block into the input