# How do I get text to display below an anchor?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to make a button that displays your computer's current battery level. The way it works is, you click a button and in the JavaScript console, it displays your computers current battery level. Instead of putting the level in the console, is there a way to display the level below the anchor tag?

```js
function batlevel() {
  navigator.getBattery().then(function(battery) {

    var level = battery.level;

    console.log(level);
  })
};
```

```html
<a onclick="batlevel()">hi</a>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS label text right below input element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463621/css-label-text-right-below-input-element)

Comment: no, not really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following.

```js
function getBatLevel(target) {
  var level;
  navigator.getBattery().then(function(battery) {
    level = (battery.level * 100);
    if (target == undefined) {
      console.log(level + "%");
    } else {
      target.after(" " + level + "%");
    }
  });
};
```

```html
<a onclick="getBatLevel(this)">Get Level</a>
```

This makes use of the `.after()` call: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/after

You can wrap it in a Element if you choose.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty straight forward. Get the element you want to append to, create a tag, set innerText and then append

```js
function batlevel() {
  navigator.getBattery().then(function(battery) {

    var level = battery.level;
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    
    p.innerText = level;
    
    document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].append(p)

    console.log(level);
  })
};
```

```html
<a onclick="batlevel()">hi</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function batlevel() {
  navigator.getBattery().then(function(battery) {

    var level = battery.level;

    console.log(level);
    document.getElementById('levelId').innerHTML = 'this is the level' + level;
  })
};

<a onclick="batlevel()">hi</a>
<div id="levelId"></div>
```