# CSS for label under input

Tags: html, css

I need a clean way of placing the label below the text input field in the following fiddle. The label needs to be center aligned to the input

```css
.scale-options {
  margin-top: 56px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 1100px;
}

.scale-yes,
.scale-no,
.scale-weight {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.scale-yes,
.scale-no {
  width: 313px;
}

.scale-weight input {
  width: 233px;
  display: block;
}

.scale-weight label {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="scale-options">
  <div class="scale-yes">
    <Button>yes</Button>
  </div>
  <div class="scale-weight">
    <input type="text" name="scaleWeight" value="24.5kg" disabled>
    <label for="scaleWeight" class="scale-weight-label">12.5</label>
  </div>
  <div class="scale-no">
    <Button>no</Button>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/chalcrow/wzpduq2h/3/

I've tried a number of ways of doing it, like setting `display:block` for both the input and label, and using `clear: both` on both elements. I've also tried a positioning hack by setting the relative position of the label, but it breaks parts of the other layout for some reason. I've also tried setting heights and widths for the input and label and tried the suggestion here https://stackoverflow.com/a/3463670/1549918 (there are other suggested answers on that question - I looked at them all and they're either too hacky or aren't working when I try them)

Comment: Please 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details. Please also read: [Can I just link to my website?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/) which also applies to any other external resources such as codepens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is, that you declared `display: inline-flex` for `.scale-weight` and as such use flexbox with the default `flex-direction: row` Just remove the class selector from the list where you declare flexbox on it. After that you can align the text of the label with `text-align: center;`

```css
.scale-options {
  margin-top: 56px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.scale-yes,
.scale-no /* , *//* removed */
/* .scale-weight *//* removed */ {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.scale-yes,
.scale-no 
 {
  width: 313px;
}

.scale-weight input {
  width: 233px;
  display: block;
}

.scale-weight label {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  /* position: relative; *//* removed as it doesn't do anything and has no absolute child */
  text-align: center; /* added */
}
```

```html
<div class="scale-options">
  <div class="scale-yes">
    <Button>yes</Button>
  </div>
  <div class="scale-weight">
    <input type="text" name="scaleWeight" value="24.5kg" disabled>
    <label for="scaleWeight" class="scale-weight-label">12.5</label>
  </div>
  <div class="scale-no">
    <Button>no</Button>
  </div>
</div>
```